# How to retrieve value counts from table as separate columns with column name as value name using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

My data looks like below in table

| ID | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2/2/2022 | Check |
| 2 | 4/3/2022 | UPI |
| 3 | 4/3/2022 | Cash |
| 4 | 4/3/2022 | Check |
| 5 | 5/6/2022 | UPI |

I trying to get the output in the following format:

| ID | Date | Check | UPI | Cash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2/2/2022 | 1 |  | 1 |
| 2 | 4/3/2022 |  | 2 |  |
| 3 | 4/3/2022 | 2 | 3 | 2 |

No idea how can I get it done can some one please help me with the SQL query through which I can do it

Comment: you need to apply groupby based on type

Comment: provide a fiddle if possible, it is not that clear.

Comment: Can you explain how the output table populated from the input table? what about ids 4 and 5?

Answer (score -1):

I think the query below may help you.

```
select Date, 
case when Type = 'Check' then cnt else null end as Check,
case when Type = 'UPI' then cnt else null end as UPI,
case when Type = 'Cash' then cnt else null end as Cash from
(select Date,Type,count(*) as cnt from table_a group by Date,Type) as temp
```

Comment: the query is wrong just ran it on fiddler, it returns one per type and per day.

Comment: Your demand is a little bit unclear. I guess you want to count each 'Type' per day, and display them in the format as the same output format you have provided.   And if there are two or more records with the same type and date in the input table, the query will return what you want. or maybe I misunderstood  your needs.